# Copy names in separate columns

Tags: indexing, google-sheets, copy, pattern-matching, match

So I have in googlesheet F1 a list of names, family names

```
ColA : Family Name                
ColB : Name
```

And I want to copy in another sheet F2 :

```
ColA : Family Name
ColB : Name1       
ColC : Name2      
ColD : Name3
```

How do i do that?

In B2 I put this formula :

```
=iferror(index('F1'!$B2:$B$2000; match(A2;'F1'!$A2:$A$2000;0);""))
```

it's working fine

My problem is when I tried to fill the C,D,... columns : if I put the same formula, it's giving me the same values as in column F2!B. I've tried tweaking the formula in B2 :

```
=iferror(index('F1'!$B3:$B$2000;match(A2;'F1'!$A3:$A$2000;0);""))
```

it's working for the first line, but not the rest.

Please help me!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and checkout [ask].

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are looking for either `FILTER` or `QUERY` whose output should be `TRANSPOSE`d:

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTER(Sheet1!B:B,Sheet1!A:A="Family Name"))
```

or

```
=TRANSPOSE(QUERY(Sheet1!A:B,"select B where A = 'Family Name'" ))
```

See this [Google Forum page](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/3Fo65nz2xiY).

[image]